# Is there a way to override a static twig template?

Tags: 8, theming

So I have 2 themes. The main custom theme we are using and bootstrap as a secondary theme that supports it.

However, there are some things that appear on the page that are only there because of bootstraps twig templates. Is there a way I can override these with my custom templates without editing bootstraps twig templates?

Here is a example:

```
{% if title %}
  <h1{{ title_attributes.addClass('page-header') }}>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

This is bootstraps page title and I would like to remove it without editing bootstraps twig templates. Is there a way I can overwride this with my templates? I already made a custom page twig template, but it adds bootstraps as well.

Comment: I don't understand - you override the twig template and it still what, adds that class? Adds attributes?

Comment: I want to remove the title completely, but I can't edit bootstrap templates as I would like to leave them be. But it only gets generated via bootstrap and not my custom theme template.

Comment: Copy that template file to your theme's /templates folder. Remove that line, flush all caches.